# Nginx is getting old ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, subdomain

My ssl certificate has expired and I have created a new one using Startssl. I have followed the steps for Nginx server that I have found in the FAQs from Startssl but, although the paths to the certificate and the key are correct, when I try to load the website with any browser it always gets the old certificate instead of the new one. Do anyone knows what can be happening?

Thanks!

March 22th UPDATE:

I have found something of what is happening: we have 2 web servers in AWS and a Load balancer. I have seen the load balancer has also the ssl certificate and I guess I have to update it too. I have done it and now the new certificate is in usage. But I still see an error: the server cannot check my domain because my certificate comes from one of my subdomains. When I created the certificate in StartSSL there was an step that asks me for a subdomain. It said the certificate will be for the domain and subdomain, but now I'm getting this message. Any idea?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx after updating the certificate (and if necessary, the `ssl_certificate` directing in the nginx configuration)?

Comment: @frasertweedale Yes, I executed "service nginx restart" after updating nginx configuration. In the configuration file I had this, before changes: "ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_name.crt;" and "ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_name.pem;" And after he changes: "ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/support.crt;" and "ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/support.pem;". Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer:

When StartSSL asked for a subdomain when I was following the steps to get the new certificate, I was indicating one of my real subdomains. If I set as subdomain "www" everything works. So I wanted to share my experience with everyone hoping it helps:

First: when you are asked for a subdomain in StartSSL, set it as "www".

Second: If you are using AWS and you have a load balancer, don't forget to update the SSL certificate in the load balancer, using the AWS NETWORK & SECURITY -> Load balancers option (Listeners tab).

Hope it helps.

Thanks for reading and trying to help me.

Comment: Geez, I never thought of that, we were giving our users secure connections by adding listeners to our balancer in AWS, then we moved to our own server... turns out the user having problems had  an expired certificate in the balancer but it was ok in our server, removing the expired listener from the balancer did the trick.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice to read it has been useful for you, Gustavo, even 4 years after! Thanks for your feedback :)